# How to Supply two different DC voltages using High Current

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, stepper-motor, circuit-design, electronics

I'm trying to function a 12V stepper motor(>2.5A) and five 6V servos(>3A). Are there any reliable circuits that can output both these voltages and a high output current since there will be some weight on these motors? (Servos MG996R)/(Stepper Nema 17)

[image]

**Reference**

- [MG996R Servo Motor (Digital)](https://www.jsumo.com/mg996r-servo-motor-digital)
- [12V & 5V Combo power supply](https://www.circuitstoday.com/12v-5v-combo-power-supply)

Comment: Simple answer is yes, but I think you need add some more detail to help you answer your question. Also is this a servo that is referenced in your question.  https://www.jsumo.com/mg996r-servo-motor-digital

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena yes that's the servo. regarding details, I'm going to supply this "dual dc power supply (using a single circuit)" by using an AC transformer. the circuit must be able to output two different DC voltages, 12V & 6V, and an output current of more than 6A. I was thinking something similar to the one below but this circuit only outputs 1A.                                            
    https://www.circuitstoday.com/12v-5v-combo-power-supply

Comment: Are you planning to use the traditional transformer+rectifier+capacitor power supply circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Just use 2 separate supplies (with appropriate current ratings). Or a 12V supply and a buck regulator.

There are power supplies with 2 outputs, but they are generally designed for a specific purpose, eg. PC power supplies which can provide 12V and 5V. I am not aware of any common dual supply that provides 12V and 6V.